# Python equivalent for batch Choice command

Tags: python, batch-file, character-limit

I'm working on a small project in python, and after a bit of work on it I was wondering if there was a way of inputting data in python 3 which was somewhat similar to batch's choice command. Pretty much only take in one key of input and then end the input prompt.

For example:

```
Choice(['Y', 'N'], "Yes or No? ")
```

Where the user could either press "Y" or "N" and the program would continue.

I've done some brief surfing, but haven't found anything I can use.

#### Bonus:

What would be even more useful is if this "choice" command could except multiple characters.

Pretty much `input` but capping the limit of characters they can input, and then immediately continuing. The latter of which is proving to be hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in for this, but you could do something like this:

```
def choice(options, prompt):
    while True:
        output = input(prompt)    # Use raw_input(prompt) for Python 2.x
        if output in options:
            return output
        else:
            print("Bad option. Options: " + ", ".join(options))
```

This would let the user enter in arbitrary strings (of any length) into the command line, and would continue once the user hits `enter`. Unfortunately, there's no easy way that I know of to automatically stop after a set number of characters.

However, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510357/646543) does discuss ways of grabbing a single character from the command line. You may be able to adapt it into the above function so that it will automatically continue after a certain number of characters, without waiting for the `enter` key to be pressed.

Comment: Ok, I'll look further into this. Thank you